# Mystery Diode in Schematic - MPQ8039 HALF BRIDGE DRIVER

Tags: driver, bootstrap

The below image shows four example schematics for the the MPQ8039 Half Bridge Driver. Three of the four examples show a diode connected between the DRV pin (Gate Drive Supply Bypass) and the BS pin (Bootstrap  Supply). The Function Block Diagram shows an internal bootstrap diode, so I'm curious as to why the schematics show and external diode for three of the four examples. The datasheet has zero information about adding an external diode.

**Why would the audio amplifier and DC converter circuit require an additional diode, but the motor driver not?**

I'm interested in using two of these driver IC's to drive a transformer with 20-80kHz square wave. My circuit is more similar to the examples with the external diode, so the lack of documentation about the diode is disturbing.

Datasheet is [HERE](https://www.monolithicpower.com/pub/media/document/MPQ8039_r1.02_Under_Development.pdf).

[image: MPQ8039 – HIGH CURRENT POWER HALF BRIDGE]

Comment: I got nothing other than that they want to reduce heat in the IC at the presumably higher frequencies of the audio circuits which you would think the IC should be able to handle since it was designed for 1.2MHz anyways.

Comment: @Toor I'd say it's definitely something to do switching speed / alternating current direction - where as the motor circuit may PWM switch rapidly, but current will continue in the same direction.  I've already purchased some of these and I'm laying out a PCB, I'm just going to put a schottky there to avoid problems. This datasheet is horrible. I can't help but notice that bridge is mis-spelled "brigde" in the linked image.

Comment: The examples say nothing about the size of the boostrap capacitor, which would need to be larger to avoid discharging excessively when the high side FET is on at low frequencies. The bigger cap would produce higher peak charging currents, but the examples say nothing about the operating frequency either,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal BS diode but for full diversion of IC heat at high commutation rates with cycle discharging the internal PFET  Miller Capacitance, external diodes were used to handle higher gate currents.

The motor could use lower commutation frequency than audio and thus the  BS cap discharge current rate is lower.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy_EE75 Thanks for the answer. Do you know if it is standard / best practice to supplement the internal bootstrap diode of driver IC's when operating over certain frequencies / commutation cycle rates? Or is it dependent on driver capability? It seems that neccessary information to make the determination is missing from the datasheet. I will be switching a transformer primary in H-bridge configuration (2 IC's) between 20kHz and 80kHz - 300mA average draw / 3A peak for short bursts (50ms) when at certain frequencies. I "assume" the external diode will be smart for my circuit?

Comment: I guess that's why a prototype must be done to verify the thermal properties and sensitivity to passive parts and diodes. You can always delete easier than adding.